# Can i use .dll library targeted .net framework v3.5 in application having targeted framework 4.0?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, dll, datagrid, .net-framework-version

Hello currently I'm working on desktop application using WPF. I create application by targeting .net framework 4.0. but I have facing some problems related targeted frameworks.

First there is a library which i have to use in my application.A library supports targeted .net framework v3.5 but I also want to use the **DataGrid** control (only available above than v4.0 targeted .net framework) for table so now i'm confuse what i should do now? how can i achieve my goal? i want to use both library + Datagrid control in my application which is targeting .net framework v4.0.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A library built for .NET Framework 3.5 will run without any issues on .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Ok lemme check it today.. brother. Thanks.

Comment: @uxmanali Did you meet any error with your .Net framework 4.0 project?

Comment: No it works perfectly fine .Thanks. @dymanoid